# How to create duplicate values of each row and then insert a new dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image: Suppose i have a pyspark data frame as]

[image: And i have another dataframe as]

How do I duplicate each row of my original dataframe and then add dataframe 2 so that my final output is: I am writing this in python in a pyspark dataframe.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want is cross join :

```
result = df1.crossJoin(df2)

result.show()

#+------+--------+------+-------+------------+-----------------+
#|  name| address|salary|bonus %|allowances %|employee category|
#+------+--------+------+-------+------------+-----------------+
#|   Tom| Chicago| 75000|      5|           5|           onsite|
#|   Tom| Chicago| 75000|     10|          10|        off shore|
#|Martha|New york| 80000|      5|           5|           onsite|
#|Martha|New york| 80000|     10|          10|        off shore|
#|Samuel| Phoenix| 90000|      5|           5|           onsite|
#|Samuel| Phoenix| 90000|     10|          10|        off shore|
#|   Rom|  Dallas| 65000|      5|           5|           onsite|
#|   Rom|  Dallas| 65000|     10|          10|        off shore|
#+------+--------+------+-------+------------+-----------------+
```